# SQL 2008 Stored Procedure with Parameters from SQL Query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that has sever parameters that need declaring when its executed. I'm trying to establish a way of using the results of a query to assign a value to one of the parameters.

For example

```
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[usp_Stored_Proc_demo]
        @tableName = N'tbltesting',
        @Col1 = N'c1',
        @Col2 = N'c2',
        @Col3 = N'c3',
        @Col4 = (SELECT GETDATE()),
        @Col5 = N'c5',
        @Col6 = N'c6',
        @Col7 = N'v7',
        @Col8 = N'c8'
```

However this doesnt work, or anything else I have tried. Is there a way of doing it??

Answer (score 0):

The options open to you really involve executing the pre-query first, assign the value to a variable and then use than in the sproc call:

```
SELECT @MyVar = Something
FROM dbo.Somewhere
WHERE WhatIAmLookingFor = 'AnAnswer'

EXECUTE dbo.MySproc @MyVar
```

You can't assign parameter values inline like you want to do based on the results of another query. You could do something using dynamic SQL I expect, but would advise against unless you have a really strong reason/need.